# Cataloging digital media to a MySQL database

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I understand .NET very well until Principles of OOP come into view, so I guess we can say very little. So to work on this, I am making a console app that will catalog my digital media to a MySQL database. I've been working on this for a few days. It's not done but I also don't want to get to far ahead and find out that this is a tragic design mess.

1. I'm employing a `using` alias directive, which is the only way that I found that will work but I don't like how I have named it and it seems very patchy. Any ideas or insight on its use and naming structure?
2. Please ignore the use of hard coding MySQL properties. I will be adding them to a config file later on.
3. I was debating on using MSSQL Server or MySQL, so I was aiming to decouple my Data Access Layer as best that I can. I don't like how I have to hard code the column names and types. Is there any better way?

```
 * Program.cs
    * [Business]
        * BusinessController.cs
        * AlbumArtist.cs
        * MusicFile.cs
    * [Data]
        * DataAccessController.cs
        * [MySQL]
            * MySQL.cs
            * [Select]
                * AlbumArtist.cs
            * [Update]
                * AlbumArtist.cs
            * [Delete]
                * AlbumArtist.cs
            * [Insert]
                * AlbumArtist.cs
```

## Program.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using TagLib;
using MediaExporter.Business;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace MediaExporter
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("## Media Exporter ##");
            Console.WriteLine("## Version 0.1 / 05.09.13 ##");
            Console.WriteLine("## Jon Holderman ##");
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.Write("Enter Media Directory: ");
            string mediaDirectory = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine();

            List<MusicFile> musicFiles = new List<MusicFile>();

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(mediaDirectory, "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {

                TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(files[i]);
                MusicFile mf = new MusicFile();

                mf.AlbumArtist = f.Tag.AlbumArtists.First(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
                mf.Genre = f.Tag.Genres.First(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
                mf.AlbumTitle = f.Tag.Album;
                mf.Year = Convert.ToInt32(f.Tag.Year);
                mf.Type = f.MimeType;
                mf.TrackNumber = Convert.ToInt32(f.Tag.Track);
                mf.TrackTitle = f.Tag.Title;
                mf.Duration = f.Properties.Duration;
                mf.Bitrate = f.Properties.AudioBitrate;
                mf.FileSize = GetFileSizeInMB(files[i]);
                mf.FilePath = files[i].ToString().Remove(0, 8);

                musicFiles.Add(mf);

                BusinessController BC = new BusinessController();

                BC.AddMusicFileToDB(mf);

            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public static decimal GetFileSizeInMB(string filePath)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
            return (fi.Length / 1024) / 1024;
        }

    }
}
```

#### Business/BusinessController.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MediaExporter.Data;

namespace MediaExporter.Business
{
    public class BusinessController
    {

        public DataAccessController DAC = new DataAccessController();

        public void AddMusicFileToDB(MusicFile musicFile)
        {
            if(isAlbumArtist(musicFile.AlbumArtist))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Album Artist is in DB...");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Album Artist is not in DB...");
            }
        }

        private bool isAlbumArtist(string albumArtistName)
        {
            return DAC.isAlbumArtist(albumArtistName);
        }

    }
}
```

#### Business/MusicFile.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MediaExporter.Business
{
    public class MusicFile
    {

        public string AlbumArtist { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public string AlbumTitle { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int TrackNumber { get; set; }
        public string TrackTitle { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
        public decimal FileSize { get; set; }
        public int Bitrate { get; set; }
        public string FilePath { get; set; }

        public MusicFile(string albumArtist, string genre, string albumTitle, int year, string type, int trackNumber, string trackTitle, TimeSpan duration, decimal fileSize, int bitrate, string filePath)
        {
            AlbumArtist = albumArtist;
            Genre = genre;
            AlbumTitle = albumTitle;
            Year = year;
            Type = type;
            TrackNumber = trackNumber;
            TrackTitle = trackTitle;
            Duration = duration;
            FileSize = fileSize;
            Bitrate = bitrate;
            FilePath = filePath;
        }

        public MusicFile()
        {

        }

    }
}
```

#### Business/AlbumArtist.cs

```cs
using System;
using MediaExporter.Data;

namespace MediaExporter.Business
{
    class AlbumArtist
    {

        public DataAccessController DAC = new DataAccessController();

        public int AlbumArtistID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }

        public AlbumArtist(int albumArtistID, string name, int rating)
        {
            AlbumArtistID = albumArtistID;
            Name = name;
            Rating = rating;
        }

        public AlbumArtist()
        {

        }

        public bool isAlbumArtist(string albumArtistName)
        {

            if (DAC.isAlbumArtist(albumArtistName))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

#### Data/DataAccessController.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MediaExporter.Data
{
    public class DataAccessController
    {

        public Data.MySQL.Select.AlbumArtist albumArtist = new MySQL.Select.AlbumArtist();

        public bool isAlbumArtist(string albumArtistName)
        {
            return albumArtist.isAlbumArtist(albumArtistName);

        }
    }
}
```

#### Data/MySQL/MySQL.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace MediaExporter.Data.MySQL
{
    public class MySQL
    {

        public string ServerAddress = "xxx";
        public string UserName = "xxx";
        public string Password = "xxx";
        public string DataBase = "xxx";
        public MySqlConnection MySqlConnection;

        public MySQL()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            MySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        }

        public void OpenConnection()
        {

            try
            {
                MySqlConnection.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException exception)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + exception.Message);
            }

        }

        public void CloseConnection()
        {

            try
            {
                MySqlConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (MySqlException exception)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + exception.Message);
            }

        }

        private string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return String.Format("SERVER={0};DATABASE={1};UID={2};PASSWORD={3};", ServerAddress, DataBase, UserName, Password);
        }

    }
}
```

This is where the `using` alias directive is located:

#### Data/MySQL/Select/AlbumArtist.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MediaExporter.Business;

namespace MediaExporter.Data.MySQL.Select
{

    using B_AlbumArtist = MediaExporter.Business.AlbumArtist;

    public class AlbumArtist : MediaExporter.Business.AlbumArtist
    {

        MySQL MySQLData = new MySQL();

        public bool isAlbumArtist(string albumArtistName)
        {

            int count = 0;

            try
            {

                MySqlConnection mySQLCnn = MySQLData.MySqlConnection;

                string query = "SELECT Count(AlbumArtistID) FROM AlbumArtist WHERE AlbumArtist.Name = @AlbumArtistName;";

                MySQLData.OpenConnection();

                using (MySqlCommand mySQLCmd = new MySqlCommand(query, mySQLCnn))
                {

                    mySQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AlbumArtistName", albumArtistName);

                    count = int.Parse(mySQLCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
            }

            if (count >= 1)
            {
                return true;
            }

            MySQLData.CloseConnection();

            return false;

        }

        public int GetAlbumArtistID(string albumArtistName)
        {

            int albumArtistID = -1;

            try
            {

                MySqlConnection mySQLCnn = MySQLData.MySqlConnection;

                string query = "SELECT ALbumArtistID FROM AlbumArtist WHERE AlbumArtist.Name = @AlbumArtistName;";

                MySQLData.OpenConnection();

                using (MySqlCommand mySQLCmd = new MySqlCommand(query, mySQLCnn))
                {

                    mySQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AlbumArtistName", albumArtistName);

                    albumArtistID = (int)mySQLCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
            }

            MySQLData.CloseConnection();

            return albumArtistID;

        }

        public string GetAlbumArtistName(int albumArtistID)
        {

            string albumArtistName = String.Empty;

            try
            {

                MySqlConnection mySQLCnn = MySQLData.MySqlConnection;

                string query = "SELECT Name FROM AlbumArtist WHERE AlbumArtist.AlbumArtistID = @AlbumArtistID;";

                MySQLData.OpenConnection();

                using (MySqlCommand mySQLCmd = new MySqlCommand(query, mySQLCnn))
                {

                    mySQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AlbumArtistID", albumArtistID);

                    albumArtistName = mySQLCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
            }

            MySQLData.CloseConnection();

            return albumArtistName;

        }

        public List<B_AlbumArtist> GetAllAlbumArtists()
        {

            List<B_AlbumArtist> albumArtistList = new List<B_AlbumArtist>();

            try
            {

                MySqlConnection mySQLCnn = MySQLData.MySqlConnection;

                string query = "SELECT * FROM AlbumArtist;";

                MySQLData.OpenConnection();

                using (MySqlCommand mySQLCmd = new MySqlCommand(query, mySQLCnn))
                {

                    MySqlDataReader mySQLReader = mySQLCmd.ExecuteReader();

                    B_AlbumArtist tempAlbumArtist = new B_AlbumArtist();

                    while (mySQLReader.Read())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < mySQLReader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {

                            tempAlbumArtist.AlbumArtistID = mySQLReader.GetInt32("AlbumArtistID");
                            tempAlbumArtist.Name = mySQLReader.GetString("Name");
                            tempAlbumArtist.Rating = mySQLReader.GetInt32("Rating");

                            albumArtistList.Add(tempAlbumArtist);

                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
            }

            MySQLData.CloseConnection();

            return albumArtistList;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using an ORM, like Entity Framework? Also, you didn't have to include all that code if you want feedback about the `using`.

Comment: @svick - I have, but I dont want to get to far ahead while I am still not understanding OOP concepts. Would you reccomend that if I was still learning OOP design? Part (3) of my question was related to folder structure and namespace structure of the program and I was hoping to get an assessment of the OOP design that I have so far. I hope that is not a far reach with this question.

Comment: @JonH - ORMs make OOP easier.  You can actually deal with objects and storing them in the database, without worrying about *how* they connect.  That being said, this design is poor even for a non-ORM design.  Consider what is involved in adding an `AlbumArtwork` class, or just an `Artist` class that groups `AlbumArtist`s together?  You'd have to duplicate four files for each new class...  Look into "Code-first Entity Framework"

Comment: @Bobson - Thanks for the input I will be looking into "Code First Entity Framework"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial formatting suggestions:

1. Class members should be `camelCase`, or _camelCase with an _ in front of them.
2. No need to keep empty constructors around your code.  They are put in by default by the compiler.
3. For non-static classes, initialize class members in the constructor, that's what they are there for.
4. Methods in C# should be `PascalCase`
5. I would read up on the `var` keyword for declaring local variables.
6. Catch specific exceptions in your try/catch blocks.  This will allow specific targeting of exceptions, and make debugging / reporting much easier.

Overall, you seems to have a good basic understanding of OOP, and your code is well formatted with mostly well named variables, making it really easy to scan and get an understanding of what you are doing.

You should look into dependency injection(DI) as a next step.  Doing DI brings out much of the power of OOP.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! Since I am new here, how bad is it for me to repost a similar questions perhaps a month or two from now with a refresh of what I changed?

Comment: @JonH - Nope, not at all.  You can link back to this question, but as long as you frame it as a new one (i.e. "This is what I have, how is it?", rather than "this is what's new, were the changes good?"), it's perfectly fine to ask again.